# roll a dice two times. Calculate covariance $\mathbb{C}ov(X,Y)$ . Calculate correlation coefficient.

Tags: probability, random-variables, dice, covariance, correlation

Here is the situation:
We a roll a  fair dice $2$ times. ( independent )

$a)$ $X$ denotes the number of the first throw; $Y$ denotes the sum of the two throws.
Calculate $\mathbb{C}ov(X,Y)$. Calculate the correlation coefficient$\phi_{X,Y}$.

$b)$ now $X$ denotes the lower number and $Y$ denotes the higher number. Calculate the covariance and the corelation coefficient.

What have I tried? Success with $a): U,W  $~ Laplace({$1,...,6$}). So $X = U$  and $ Y = U + W $.  $ Cov(X,Y) = Cov(U,U+W) = Cov(U,U) + Cov(U,W) = Var(U) + 0 = Var(U) = \frac{35}{12} $. For $\phi_{X,Y}$ I used the formula.

But I have a problem with b) and hope that somebody can fix it.  I'm very much aware that this it is pretty similar to a). So let's say: $U, W$~ Laplace({$1,...,6$}) now $X$ has to be $min(U,W)$ and $Y=max(U,W)$. Consider $Cov(X,Y) = Cov(min(U,W),max(U,W))$. But what do I now?

Comment: What is $\ \mathbb Cov\ $ ? ... and the correlation coefficien $\ \Phi_{X\ Y}\ $ ?

Comment: Hello Wlod AA. Covariance. I will edit it.

Comment: Correlation coefficient is defined as  $\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{sqrt(Var(X))sqrt(Var(Y))}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't immediately see a really quick way of doing this so I would proceed as follows.

The definition of covariance is (equivalent to)
$$Cov(X,Y) = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y].$$
Now calculate $E[XY]$, $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ directly by first finding the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$. You should get $E[X]=\frac{91}{36}, \, \, E[Y]= \frac{161}{36}$ and $E[XY]=\frac{441}{36}$.

Maybe the easiest way to find $E[XY]$ is to note that it's equal to $E[UV]$ when $X = min(U,V)$ and $Y = max(U,V)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I got this. Found a tiny mistake I think: You mean $E(Y) = \frac{161}{36} $, right? I'm really curious if there is another way, but nevertheless i like and understand your calculation :)

Comment: @Memories Yes that is a typo. Fixed it!