# Understanding how $E(X)=\frac{91}{36}$ was calculated

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I've found an [older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2569649/215011) here and I just can't understand how they got these values. The question says:

"We a roll a fair dice 2 times. ( independent ):

a) X denotes the number of the first throw; Y denotes the sum of the two throws. Calculate Cov(X,Y). Calculate the correlation coefficient ϕX,Y."

I know the formula $cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$ and in the answers they calculated E[X] = 91/36. How did they reach this number? From my understanding the mean should be 1 * 1/6 + 2 * 1/6 + ... + 6 * 1/6 = 21/6. What am I missing?

Comment: Please link to the other question.  You can click edit below your question, highlight some text, and click on the chain to insert a link.  You are correct that $E[X]=\frac{21}6$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question you found is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2569649/215011), the expectation $E(X)=\frac{91}{36}$ is referring to part (b).
You are correct that in part (a), $E(X)=\frac72$.

To get the value $\frac{91}{36}$, construct a $6\times 6$ table of all outcomes of the experiment. The $36$ possible values for (first roll, second roll) are
$$
\begin{matrix}(1,1)&(1,2)&(1,3)&(1,4)&(1,5)&(1,6)\\
(2,1)&(2,2)&(2,3)&(2,4)&(2,5)&(2,6)\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\\
(5,1)&(5,2)&(5,3)&(5,4)&(5,5)&(5,6)\\
(6,1)&(6,2)&(6,3)&(6,4)&(6,5)&(6,6)
\end{matrix}
$$
Here are the corresponding values for $X:=$ smaller of the two rolls:
$$
\begin{matrix}1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&2&2&2&2&2\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\\
1&2&3&4&5&5\\
1&2&3&4&5&6
\end{matrix}
$$
Since all $36$ outcomes are equally likely, count up the occurrences of $1,2,\ldots,6$ to obtain $P(X=1)=\frac{11}{36}$, $P(X=2)=\frac{9}{36}$, $P(X=3)=\frac7{36}$, $P(X=4)=\frac5{36}$, $P(X=5)=\frac3{36}$, $P(X=6)=\frac1{36}$, and finally compute $E(X)=\frac{91}{36}$.

Comment: In this question $X$ is the number on the first die.  In the question you link to $X$ is the lower of the two numbers while $Y$ is the higher of the two numbers.  That changes the expectation values.

Comment: @RossMillikan Right!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, I finally understand now. @grand_chat

Comment: @OscarTheMighty You are welcome. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2810380/215011 for another application of this technique.